# Write EIO error after client disconnects from console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Node.js application with Express.js web framework. This application run on linux server. One of modules writes to console through console.log command. When client disconnects from console, application crashes with error message "write EIO". Please can anyone help me with this problem? Can i fix this problem in application settings or in server settings?

Comment: Did you try listening for the `error` event on the request or request socket object? Also, what do you mean by "when client disconnects from console?"

Comment: I do not use sockets in the application. I catch error with message "write EIO" in "uncaughtException" callback of main process. With "client disconnects from console" I mean situation, when I am connected to server in terminal, start Node process and disconnect from server. Problem occurs when application attempts write to console (console.log) and I am not connected to the server in terminal.